# How to read from the master file without affecting writing to the master file in pty using rust?

Tags: shell, rust, terminal, web-applications, pty

I try to use pty as backend to build an emulated terminal on web application which supports local shells. And I use rust `nix.openpty` to get slave and master file descriptor on linux. Like this:

```
unsafe fn spawn_pty_with_shell(default_shell: String) -> bipty {
    match openpty(None, None) {
        // Spawn successful.
        Ok(pty_res) => {
            let master = pty_res.master;
            let slave = pty_res.slave;
            println!("master fd: {}, slave fd: {}", &master, &slave);
            // If the result is a child process, spawn a new shell.
            let builder = Command::new(&default_shell)
            // Get input from the slave file descriptor.
            .stdin(Stdio::from_raw_fd(slave))
            .stdout(Stdio::from_raw_fd(slave))
            .stderr(Stdio::from_raw_fd(slave))
            .spawn()
            .expect("failed to spawn");

            // wait for 2s and then exit.
            std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(2000));

            bipty {
                process: builder,
                mfd: master,
                sfd: slave,
            }
        },
        Err(e) => {
            panic!("failed to fork {:?}", e);
        }
    }
}
```

And the I successfully implement writing to the master file functionality and it works fine. Code below:

```
// Execute a command with user input, by flushing master file descripter.
fn pty_execute(mfd: RawFd, command: &str) {
    let mut master_file = unsafe { File::from_raw_fd(mfd) };
    // Write command to the file descriptor.
    write!(master_file, "{}", command).unwrap();
    master_file.flush().unwrap();
}
```

Then the problems occurs when I try to get the output from the master file:

```
// Error: Bad file descriptor code 9.
// fn read_from_master(mfd: RawFd) -> String {
//     let mut master_file = unsafe { File::from_raw_fd(mfd) };

//     let mut read_buffer = String::new();
//     master_file.read_to_string(&mut read_buffer).unwrap(); // Execution stops here.
//     format!("Master file content: {}", read_buffer)
// }

fn read_from_master_fd(mfd: RawFd) -> String {
    let mut read_buffer: Vec<u8> = vec![];

    loop {
        match read_from_fd(mfd) {
            Some(mut read_bytes) => {
                read_buffer.append(&mut read_bytes);
            }
            None => {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    format!("{:?}", String::from_utf8(read_buffer).unwrap())
}
```

Here I implement 2 methods, the first `read_from_master` will panic and show `Bad file descriptor, code 9`, and the second `read_from_master_fd` will stuck and return nothing (The terminal will not give you any output and stuck, exit by pressing *Ctrl+C*). After all, I find no way to read content correctly from the master file and pass it as String for frontend display.

I found most rust tutorials online are either only about writing or only about reading. And I find it quite confusing to implement them correctly at the same time. It would be so great if someone willing to give some hints.

My vision is to build a rust pty backend for xtermjs (as emulated terminal frontend).

Bests.

Comment: Is the `Stdio::from_raw_fd` usage correct? In docs it is stated, that it will take ownership. But you call it 3 times, and even keep it in `bipty` (thought this would not even compile).

Comment: @jerch, yeah, your point makes sense. I ignored this problem because I thought reading & writing are only about dealing with the master file. and my focus are all on it. But the slave file should deserve the right treatment. I will definitely check this  and do some tests.